# What does backslash space mean in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

I know that something like `\x->x+1` is an anonymous function definition that gets an x and adds one to it. But I saw the expression `return x = (\ r -> x)` when I was reading an article [here](https://www.quora.com/Functional-Programming/What-are-monads-and-why-are-they-useful).

What does `(\ r -> x)` mean? Why after backslash is empty?

Comment: Because you can generally insert arbitrary many spaces between two tokens. Backslash is one token, `x` is another one.

Comment: Haskell is based on Lambda Calculus in its core. That's why such anonymous functions are possible. Basically it is achieved by Beta-reduction in `\r -> x`, where `r` is the formal parameter. Here 'r' is not bounded. However in the inc. function `\x -> + x 1` x is bounded and that means that the value of x is passed onto the variable 'x' and after a Delta-reduction it's incremented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference: `\ r -> x` or `\r -> x` have the same meaning, much as `1+1` and `1 + 1` have the same meaning. Whitespace after `\` is irrelevant.

So, `return x` is just `\r -> x`, which is a function which takes a parameter `r`, ignores it, and yields `x`.

Moreover, since `r` gets ignored, we tend to write `\ _ -> x` (or `const x` - which is defined as `const x _ = x`) instead.